# JavaScript: returning a function conditionally using && return; throws error

Tags: javascript

I would like to return a function conditionally. The following code:

```
function validate() {
    ...     

    isNotValid && return;   

}
```

throws error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return
```

I can do it using an `if` statement, but would like to know why `&&` and `return` don't go with each other.

Answer (score 3):

Each side of a boolean operator has to be an expression (and one of the two will be the **value** you get when evaluating LHS && RHS).

`return` is not an expression, so it can't go there.

Take for instance:

```
var something = 1 && return;
```

You can't assign `return` to `something`, it doesn't make sense.

Use an `if` statement. That is what `if` is designed for.